# Detect another client's http request on php

Tags: php, httprequest

I have a web server (run PHP) and two clients now. both clients are opening the web.

I want that Client A send the HTTP requests (PUT/GET) to the server, for example `POST  id = 1`

then , the server will process the requests ,like do the SQL query search the information of id = 1.

and push the query result (id , other information...)  to the Client B immediately .

What technology I should use? or other languages should I use. I hope someone can provide me a simple example.

Comment: What exactly are the roles/functions of "Client A" and "Client B". If "Client B" is only listening for inbound requests, then it doesn't really sound like a client to me.

Comment: Sounds to me like OP is asking how to make a PUB/SUB architecture for the application